# google cloud credentials for pods deployed in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a Flask application which communicates with Google cloud storage using python client library. Currently, on a local development, I am using a service account for authenticating the application and making interactions.

I am planning to build a docker image of the application and deploy it on a kubernetes cluster. My concern is that, how should I provide the Google credentials?

I might be wrong here, When I ran this python file on a VM it was able to create a new bucket without a need for credentials or service accounts.

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# The name for the new bucket
bucket_name = 'my-new-bucket'

# Creates the new bucket
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)

print('Bucket {} created.'.format(bucket.name))
```

If I dockerize the same code into flask application and deploy it on a cluster, will it still take the default google credentials? 
I would like to know the best practice of doing this on a kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to deploy a kubernetes secret

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
data:
  key.json: "Your service acount key.json"`

For the Pod/ Deployment

`volumes:
  - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    secret:
      secretName: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Then, for the image you can set the variable as 
`os.['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']` which will take the os variable inside the container and the python code will use that key.

Once you build the image push it to container registry.

That should work.

Comment: You can also use the service account of the GKE cluster. You need to make sure the scopes are set correctly to allow read / write access to GCS. It's not nearly as secure as using secrets, but it will work

Comment: @Nicolae, how do you add the GoogleStorageCredential.json. I mean in your answer "Your service acount key.json", does this refer to the file path? or paste the entire file content? Or paste the base64encoded of the file content?